# How to start Windows 7 after setting wait time = 0

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

After I installed 12.04, I think waiting a long time to choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu is such a waste.

So I went into Windows 7 and set the default to Ubuntu and no waiting time (not the grub in Ubuntu). Now I can only access Ubuntu but I have something to do with  Windows 7. I wonder how can I enter Windows 7?

There is no  Windows 7 in my Grub menu. Even if I add one in, It said no such thing. Since this is Windows 7, I can't edit `boot.ini` to fix it.

I have tried to punch <kbd>F8</kbd> or the down arrow to stop the system turn to Ubuntu but, they all failed. I just want to enter Windows 7 and change that damn waiting time.

Comment: Which tool did you use set the default to Ubuntu in Windows?

Comment: And type `sudo update-grub` to make the windows option to show in GRUB again, but you still have to wait

Comment: If you had used Grub2, to default to Ubuntu (with no wait time), then you just need to **hold down the 'Shift'-key (on startup)** to see the Grub2 menu.

Comment: @EmersonHsieh I use BSD in windows7 to set the default to Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
done
I wonder is this skipping message let win7 disappear from grub.

Comment: @david6 I use BSD in win7. Now did I realize How fool it is to use a windows boot tool.

Comment: **Agree.**  Better effort at possible solution below ..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your Hard drive or other boot device, that way it will either stay on the main bios screen or give you an error message that will let you enter setup/bios menu.

Comment: I think you didn't get the point on what the problem is in this question. Nevertheless thank you for your efforts trying to provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

***This is actually a Windows 7 / MBR problem.***

---

**STRONG CAVEATS**

- I have **not** tried this, as I have always used **Grub** for dual-boot of **Ubuntu** and **Windows**.
- Check that you have backup copies of any critical settings and user data before proceeding.

---

*If* you 'Restore your MBR", then Windows *should* boot normally.

[Restore the Windows bootloader to MBR after dual-booting with Linux](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/)

**Note:** *Some of the Windows-centric recommendations herein don't make total sense (IMHO), but the technical steps seem fairly straight forward ..*

I then *suggest* you force re-install of **Grub2** (for dual-boot).